# How to transform manually created form to a django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm currently working on a survey app. The app works well, however I did it without using django forms. Now I want to be able to use Django forms for security reasons. however I am stuck because the app has certain peculiarities that make the transition difficult. Although I have read the documentation and many posts in stackoverflow I don't find a way to do it.

**The questions are:**

What is the approach that I must follow to be able to transform this into django forms? There are several particularities that I think are important to bear in mind:

**1.** I want to render the form manually, since it is using bootstrap and there are several details of aesthetic type that I want to maintain.

**2.** All questions are loaded on the same page, and at the end of these is the send button, so it could be said that it is a single form.

**3.** It is important that the name of the input is the ID of the question, because I must know the question and the answer to that question. (I think this is one of the main problems because the name of the input is supposed to be the name of the field in the form created in forms.py, but for each question changes the attribute name of the input)

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic editing views, for more info; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

By using a CreateView you can automatically create a ModelForm

```
#views.py

from forms import AnswerCreateForm    

class AnswerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Answer
    form_class = AnswerCreateForm
```

You can then handle your validation in forms.py

```
#forms.py

class AnswerCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = []
        etc.
```

Rendering your form manually can be done with using bootstrap, read more overhere, it does require quite a bit of code. I would test the form first using {{ form }}, and afterwards render the same form manually.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually